# How to create a domain with both internal and external ips?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I was using Amazon before and there is a possibility that you can create domains like this: database.mydomain.com

Then if you ping this url from outside the server, you get the external IP, and if you ping if from an instance in the network, you get the internal IP.

How is this possible and is there a way to implement the same thing in Google Cloud? Is it about the router?

I don't know the terms for this usage. Sorry if the title is not very clear.

Comment: It's about your DNS settings.

Comment: I added A record for external ip, but how is it possible to make it show the internal ip from DNS settings?

Comment: On the machines that you want to see the internal IP, either modify their hosts files, or point them to a DNS server you run that contains the internal IP.